# Como utilizar gráficos construídos pela função ggplot em um Shiny DASHBOARD

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Estou com alguns gráficos prontos gerados pelo pacote ggplot e estou tentando construir um shiny Rdashboard e aproveitar esses produtos visuais. No entanto, está sendo bem mais complicado do que imaginei, sigo recebendo uma série de erros, como eu devo referir meus objetos ggplot prontos no back.end do shiny dash board?

Vou colocar um pedaço do script do dash para exemplificar melhor a situação.

"scriptsimp" é um objeto que refere o nome do arquivo do script que gera os gráficos pelo ggplot
"SS_GRAPH" é o nome de um objeto gráfico criado pelo ggplot

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)

source(scriptsimp)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(title = 'SIM-P'),
  dashboardSidebar(
    menuItem("Geral", tabName = "Geral"),
    menuItem("2020", tabName = "2020"),
    menuItem("2021", tabName = "2021")
  ),
  dashboardBody(tabItem(
    tabName = 'Geral', 
      fluidRow(plotOutput("ss"))
  )
    
  )
   
  )


source(scriptsimp)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ss <-renderPlotly({SS_GRAPH)}
```

Comment: Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi exatamente o que você precisa, mas notei um detalhe que pode te ajudar. Você precisa definir o renderPlot para renderizar seu gráfico.

```
output$meu_grafico <- renderPlot({
     ggplot(
      my_df,
      aes(y = y, x = x, fill = dados)
    ) +
      geom_col()
```

Ainda na parte de ui, você coloca onde o gráfico fica. Exemplo:

```
fluidRow(
      plotOutput("meu_grafico")
    )
```